# How can I generate a list of every valid syntactic operator in Bash including input and output?

Tags: bash

According to the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Indexes.html), the Bash scripting language is constituted of 4 distinct subclasses of syntactic elements:

- built-in commands (`alias`, `cd`)
- reserved words (`if`, `function`)
- parameters and variables (`$`, `IFS`)
- functions (`abort`, `end-of-file` - activated with keybindings such as `Ctrl-d`)

Apart from reading the manual, I became inherently curious if there was a programmatic way to list out or generate all such keywords, at least from one of the above categories. I think this could be useful in some contexts. Sometimes I wish I could see all the options available to me for what I can write in any given moment, and having that information as data, instead of a formatted manual, is convenient, focused, and can be edited, in case you want to strike out commands you know well, or that are too obscure for now.

My understanding is that Bash takes the input into stdin and passes it to the running shell process. When code is distributed in a production-ready form, it is compiled, so it runs faster. Unlike using a Python REPL, you don’t have access to the Bash source code from within Bash, so it is not a very direct route to write a program that searches through source files to find various defined commands. I mean that if you wanted to list all functions, Python has the `dir()` function which programmatically looks for function names in the namespace. But I don’t think Bash can do that. I think it doesn’t have a special syntax in its source files which makes it easy to find and identify all the keywords. Instead, they will be found if you simply enter them - like `cd` will “find” the program `cd` because `$PATH` returns the path to that command - but there’s no special way to *discover* them.

Or am I wrong? Technically, you could run a “brute force” search by generating every combination of symbols of every length and record when you did not get “error: unknown command” as a response.

Is there any other clever programmatic way to do this?

Comment: for `GNU bash` you might try obtaining a copy of the source code which should give you access to the parser and list of 'reserved words', from there I'm assuming you could find your list of 'syntactic operators' ... [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)

Comment: 'course, some commands (eg, `ls`) are not part of `bash` but instead a binary that `bash` finds in `$PATH`; other commands may be part of `bash` (eg, a builtin) and also a binary (eg, `test`, `printf`); from the `bash` command prompt a simple `help` will display a mix of shell builtins and keywords

Comment: I think you'd be much better off spending some time learning shell syntax first, because the question doesn't really make sense in terms of how shell syntax actually works. For one thing, shell syntax is extremely context-dependent, and something that functions as one "operator" in one context will often mean something completely different -- or nothing special at all -- in other contexts. I think you'd better get an understanding of what the relevant concepts are before trying to make a massive list of things that may or may not relate into those concepts.

Comment: @Gordon Davisson the meaning of a symbol may change in a new context, but couldn’t that new context be considered something other than strictly Bash? Like, maybe it’s a Regex. Or maybe it’s a flag for a specific command line utility. Would that be a conceptually valid way of differentiating between “Bash” and “non-Bash”?

Comment: Can anyone suggest a way to improve the question to improve the score? I’m trying to improve my posts. Stack Overflow says I have too many poor quality ones. Thank you.

Comment: I did a first attempted edit. Will probably do a second one in time. Any suggested edits / help are welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> I mean I want to see a list of every symbol or string that the bash
> compiler

Bash is not a *compiler*.  It and every other shell I know are *interpreters* of various languages.

> recognises and knows what to do with, including commands like
> “ls” or just a symbol like “*”. I also want to see the inputs and
> outputs for each symbol, i.e., some commands are executed in the shell
> prompt by themselves, but what data type do they return?

All commands executed by the shell have an *exit status*, which is a number between 0 and 255.  This is as close to a "return type" as you get.  Many of them also produce idiosyncratic output to one or two streams (a standard output stream and a standard error stream) under some conditions, and many have other effects on the shell environment or operating environment.

> And some
> require a certain data type to standard input.

I can't think of a built-in utility whose expected input is well characterized as having a particular data type.  That's not really a stream-oriented concept.

> I want to do this just as a rigorous way to study the language.

If you want to rigorously study the language, then you should study [its manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html), where everything you describe has already been compiled.  You might also want to study [the POSIX shell command language manual](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_01) for a slightly different perspective, which is more thorough in some areas, though what it documents differs in a few details from Bash's default behavior.

If you want to compile your own summary of Bash syntax and behavior, then those are the best source materials for such an effort.

Comment: Thanks very much. However, I’m still curious to know about a programmatic way (if possible) to extract symbols the interpreter recognises, or at least a subset of them that are easy to access. Maybe I can get a list of commands from the interpreter’s code.

Comment: This is the closest to it: `help -s \* | cut -d: -f1`

Answer (score 2):

You can get a list of all reserved words and syntactic elements of bash using this trick:

```sh
help -s '*' | cut -d: -f1
```

Or more accurately:

```sh
help -s \* | awk -F ': ' 'NR>2&&!/variables/{print $1}'
```

Comment: *Some* syntactic elements.  The help text fails to cover at least quoting, all forms of expansion, and all forms of redirection, and some reserved words.  It is mostly a list of built-in commands.  (Not that a list of built-in commands is without value.)

Comment: Sorry, where I wrote "reserved words" I meant "metacharacters".  Most, perhaps all of the reserved words indeed are covered by the help text.